# WinUI 3 - Detect when a display is plugged / unplugged

Tags: c#, winui-3

I'm trying, in a WinUI 3 project, to detect when a display is plugged or unplugged. I use the following code but I do not receive any notifications:

```
public class ScreenMonitor
{
    private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
    public const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
    public const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;
    private const int DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x00000005;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
    {
        public int dbcc_size;
        public int dbcc_devicetype;
        public int dbcc_reserved;
        public Guid dbcc_classguid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
        public string dbcc_name;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hRecipient, ref DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter, int Flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hHandle);

    private IntPtr notificationHandle;

    public void StartMonitoring(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dbdi = new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
        dbdi.dbcc_size = Marshal.SizeOf(dbdi);
        dbdi.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        dbdi.dbcc_reserved = 0;
        dbdi.dbcc_classguid = Guid.Empty;

        notificationHandle = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, ref dbdi, 0);

        if (notificationHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to register for device notifications");
        }
    }

    public void StopMonitoring()
    {
        if (notificationHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            UnregisterDeviceNotification(notificationHandle);
            notificationHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DeviceChangeEventArgs> DeviceChange;

    protected virtual void OnDeviceChange(DeviceChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceChange?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public void WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (msg != WM_DEVICECHANGE)
            return;

        int wParamInt = wParam.ToInt32();
        if (wParamInt == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL || wParamInt == DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)
        {
            OnDeviceChange(new DeviceChangeEventArgs(wParamInt));
        }
    }
}

public class DeviceChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int EventType { get; }

    public DeviceChangeEventArgs(int eventType)
    {
        EventType = eventType;
    }
}
```

In the constructor of my MainWindow.xaml.cs, I use the following code:

```
_screenMonitor = new ScreenMonitor();
_screenMonitor.DeviceChange += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.EventType == ScreenMonitor.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL)
    {
        Log.Logger.Debug("Screen plugged in");
    }
    else if (e.EventType == ScreenMonitor.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)
    {
        Log.Logger.Debug("Screen removed");
    }
};

_screenMonitor.StartMonitoring(_hwnd);
```

and in the Window_Closed method, I call the _screenMonitor.StopMonitoring();

Do you know what is wrong in the code or an idea on how to detect display plugged/unplugged?

Thanks,

Philippe

Comment: Have you tried to use WinRT's DeviceInformation Watcher instead? It's much easier https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation There's a full example here https://github.com/smourier/DeviceExplorer

Comment: Besides ↑, try calling the function as `RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, ref dbdi, 4);` -- Why would your Wndproc be called, or what is `_handle`?

Comment: Monitor the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` notification to detect when settings change or when a display is added or removed. I suggest you could try to add wndproc to handle the WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message.